# How await service complete with ionic

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, types

Hello the ionic typescript code below performs a rest call to a backend, what I have to do is make sure that the call is dialed before retrying the value what can I do?

**TypeScript Code:**

```
login(username: string, password: string): Boolean {
    var retvalue=true;
     this.__user.loginService(username, password).subscribe((val) => {
     
        var ret=val.return;
        if(ret==0){
          retvalue=false;
          console.log("Login non riuscito");
        }
        else{
          console.log("Login riuscito");
        }
     
    }, response => {
      retvalue=false;
    }, () => {
      retvalue=false;
    });
   
   return retvalue;
}
```

Comment: Afaik there is no way you can return a simple boolean if you are using a async call to the backend. You can either use the async pipe in the template if you want to display something or you need to do the logic inside the subscribe to the call. If you have your logic in another function just return an Observable<boolean> and subscribe to it.

Comment: You **cannot**  return a synchronous value from an asynchronous request. You either need to use `async` pipe like @Havald says or subscribe to the observable where it's notification is required.